# how to insert layout macro above thumbnail

Tags: bixby

I want to insert tiny type above the answer set providing a bit of metadata, but can't figure out how to do it. I just want the layout macro content-answer-set-info to say something like "results in reverse chronological order" in Legal or Detail_S.  I want it to appear below altbrains workshop and above the first item in the list.

```
render {

        if (size(this) > 1) {



           list-of (this) {

            has-details (true)
            where-each (item) {
              layout-macro (content-thumbnail-card) {
                param (content) {
                  expression (item)
                }
              }
            }
          }
           }


        else-if (size(this) == 1) {
          layout-match (this) {
            mode (Details)
        }
        }
        else {layout-macro (content-zero-results) {}

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend wrapping this layout macro in a `section` and using the `section-title` ([documentation](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/layout.content.section.title)) key to give it the text above the list.

Comment: Can't figure out how to get that to work -- the list-of doesn't want to belong to a section apparently ?   updating code above.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative solution that use `section -> title` but not with `list-of`

```
  render {
    layout {
      section {
        title {
          template ("Voice command Add One")
        }
        content {
          for-each (this) {
            as (item) {
              title-card {
                title-area {
                  slot2 {
                    single-line {
                      text {
                        value {
                          template ("Integer: #{value(item.number)}")
                        }
                        style (Detail_L)
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

[image]